# Acessing C# code in Powershell

Tags: c#, powershell, hotkeys, registerhotkey

I want to use a system wide hotkey in my powershell GUI application. I found this C# code for registering a hotkey and integrated it in my script. 
The trouble is, because I can't fully understand the C# code, I don't know how to properly **add the parameters** for the registerhotkey method.

The goal is: on key press <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> execute the code in **$hotkeyExecCode**.

```
[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms")
[System.Windows.Forms.Application]::EnableVisualStyles()

$form1 = New-Object 'System.Windows.Forms.Form'
$form1.ClientSize = '200, 150'


$cCode = @"
 using System;
    using System.Diagnostics;
    using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
    using System.Threading;

    /// <summary> This class allows you to manage a hotkey </summary>
    public class GlobalHotkeys : IDisposable
    {
        [DllImport( "user32", SetLastError = true )]
        [return: MarshalAs( UnmanagedType.Bool )]
        public static extern bool RegisterHotKey (IntPtr hwnd, int id, uint fsModifiers, uint vk);
        [DllImport( "user32", SetLastError = true )]
        public static extern int UnregisterHotKey (IntPtr hwnd, int id);
        [DllImport( "kernel32", SetLastError = true )]
        public static extern short GlobalAddAtom (string lpString);
        [DllImport( "kernel32", SetLastError = true )]
        public static extern short GlobalDeleteAtom (short nAtom);

        public const int MOD_ALT = 1;
        public const int MOD_CONTROL = 2;
        public const int MOD_SHIFT = 4;
        public const int MOD_WIN = 8;

        public const int WM_HOTKEY = 0x312;

        public GlobalHotkeys()
        {
            this.Handle = Process.GetCurrentProcess().Handle;
        }

        /// <summary>Handle of the current process</summary>
        public IntPtr Handle;

        /// <summary>The ID for the hotkey</summary>
        public short HotkeyID { get; private set; }

        /// <summary>Register the hotkey</summary>
        public void RegisterGlobalHotKey(int hotkey, int modifiers, IntPtr handle)
        {
            UnregisterGlobalHotKey();
            this.Handle = handle;
            RegisterGlobalHotKey(hotkey, modifiers);
        }

        /// <summary>Register the hotkey</summary>
        public void RegisterGlobalHotKey(int hotkey, int modifiers)
        {
            UnregisterGlobalHotKey();

            try
            {
                // use the GlobalAddAtom API to get a unique ID (as suggested by MSDN)
                string atomName = Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId.ToString("X8") + this.GetType().FullName;
                HotkeyID = GlobalAddAtom(atomName);
                if (HotkeyID == 0)
                    throw new Exception("Unable to generate unique hotkey ID. Error: " + Marshal.GetLastWin32Error().ToString());

                // register the hotkey, throw if any error
                if (!RegisterHotKey(this.Handle, HotkeyID, (uint)modifiers, (uint)hotkey))
                    throw new Exception("Unable to register hotkey. Error: " + Marshal.GetLastWin32Error().ToString());

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                // clean up if hotkey registration failed
                Dispose();
                Console.WriteLine(ex);
            }
        }

        /// <summary>Unregister the hotkey</summary>
        public void UnregisterGlobalHotKey()
        {
            if ( this.HotkeyID != 0 )
            {
                UnregisterHotKey(this.Handle, HotkeyID);
                // clean up the atom list
                GlobalDeleteAtom(HotkeyID);
                HotkeyID = 0;
            }
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            UnregisterGlobalHotKey();
        }
    }
"@

Add-Type -TypeDefinition $cCode
$hotkeyExecCode = { $form1.WindowState = "normal"}

[GlobalHotkeys]::RegisterHotKey( ???????? )  # <--------- How do i add the parameters here?

$form1.windowstate = "minimized"
$form1.ShowDialog()
```

Comment: This code looks very wrong and possibly dangerous. `RegisterHotKey` takes a `HWND` -- a handle to a Win32 window -- that it sends messages to when your hot key is pressed. This code is passing a *process* handle to that function, which is just plain wrong (though I suspect in a WinForms app it might accidentially work). And even if you fixed the parameter you need to start up a message pump to receive the WM_HOTKEY and keep it running in the background, which I have no idea how to do.

Comment: Windows Forms controls already have a Handle property which should be safe to pass to RegisterHotKey

Comment: Mhm still not working. Could you make an example on how to add the parameters? Thanks!