# Global (system-wide) hotkey with Powershell

Tags: winforms, powershell, hotkeys, global-hotkey

i have a winform waitng in the back and would like to make it appear with a global (system wide) hotkey. (see bogus "new-hotkey"-cmdlet below)
I searched the web intensively but only found C# solutions, which i could not translate into powershell (v3).

```
[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms")

$form1 = New-Object 'System.Windows.Forms.Form'
$form1.ClientSize = '300, 250'
$form1.windowstate = "minimized"

# -- bogus code --
$hk = new-hotkey -scope Global -keys "Ctrl,Shift,Z" -action ({$form1.windowstate = "normal" })
# ----------------

$form1.ShowDialog()
```

thanks, Rob

Comment: I don't think you're going to be able to do that without C# code one way or another.  You could create a custom Form subclass and load it with Add-Type (which will probably match the examples you've already found), then use that form class from the PowerShell script.

Implementing something like that New-Hotkey cmdlet would be quite a bit more convoluted, but should be possible.

Comment: Thanks but you misunderstood: i dont need it as cmdlet and i have nothing against including c-code in my script. I just don't know how to do it...

Comment: This blog will get you started: http://blogs.technet.com/b/stefan_gossner/archive/2010/05/07/using-csharp-c-code-in-powershell-scripts.aspx

Comment: unfortunately it won't. I've been there, tryied to implement some c code i found. Problem is, cause i cant C#, i cant judge if the code works or not and what might be wrong. see here what happens: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23855928/acessing-c-sharp-code-in-powershell

Comment: You're going to need to learn a bit more about C# and Windows messages (Win32 API) to get this working, and getting PowerShell code to execute in response to the Win32 message is not a trivial task.  The easiest way I can think of would be to write a .NET class (subclass of Form) which raises an event in response to the message, and PowerShell code that uses Register-ObjectEvent to respond to this.  However, if you've gone to the trouble of writing a new subclass of Form anyway, you might just want to respond to the message right there in C#.